# Get "Home Directory" attribute from active directory

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, active-directory

I'm trying to get Home Directory attribute value from active directory..

I used the following code:

```
public static void GetExchangeServerByWwidLdap(string wwid)
{
    var exchange = string.Empty;

    using (var ds = new DirectorySearcher())
    {
        ds.SearchRoot = new DirectoryEntry("GC:something");
        ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

        //construct search filter
        string filter = "(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person)";
        filter += "(employeeid=" + wwid + "))";
        ds.Filter = filter;

        string[] requiredProperties = new string[] { "homeDirectory", "homemta" };

        foreach (String property in requiredProperties)
            ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add(property);

        SearchResult result = ds.FindOne();
    }      
}
```

When I check `result` object data, I'm seeing only 2 values: "homemta" and "adspath".
Where is the "homeDirectory" value?

I entered AD website and searched the same values for same users - through the website I can see the all the data I searched for so I assuming that I have code issue somewhere.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to retrieve homeDirectory from global catalog.

[It’s not there.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You can e.g. bind to the user by ADsPath property (i.e. “LDAP://…” string), then query the homeDirectory attribute of that user.

Or, if you only have a single domain, you can search within that domain instead of searching the GC. In this case you'll be able to retrieve all the properties you want.